# Pass a variable to a child component

Tags: variables, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to pass a class name as a variable to a child component.

Context: I have two types of header ( 2 different bakgrounds ) used all across the site.

Page1:

```
<HeaderMain bg="bg" />

data() {
  return {
    pageTitle: 'patterson.travel',
    bg: 'bg-white',
  }
}
```

Page:2

```
<HeaderMain bg="bg" />

data() {
  return {
    pageTitle: 'patterson.travel',
    bg: 'bg-header',
  }
}
```

HeaderMain :

```
<header>
    <nav class="main md:bg-transparent" :class="bg"></nav>
</header>
```

But the class never gets applied to the `<nav>`

I tried adding the variable to HeaderMain component like so (as a default):

```
data() {
  return {
    bg: 'bg-red', // default?
  }
}
```

But That is the class it allways has...

So, any idea what I'm missing, here?

( I also tried `:bg="bg"` )

Comment: Default variable you can add as `bg: { default: 'bg-red'}`

Comment: @varit05 Thanks, but the thing is that I don't want a default, it was just a test. I'm allways going to pass it

Comment: Look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/km24tg0r/ I have passed Background color red in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the `bg` property on your `HeaderMain` component:

```
// HeaderMain.vue

<script>
    export default {
      props: ['bg']
    }
</script>
```

You will then be able to use it in your template just like you did:

```
<header>
    <nav class="main md:bg-transparent" :class="bg"></nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access it, you need to define `props` as an array inside your children component.

Look at the code below.

```js
Vue.component('user-name', {
  props: ['name'],
  template: '<p>Hi {{ name }}</p>'
})

const LastName = {
 template: '<span> Patel </span>'
}
const Header = {
 props: ['bg'],
 template: '<span :class="bg"> {{bg}} Header </span>'
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      headerBg: 'header-bg'
    }
  },
  components: {
   'last-name': LastName,
    'header-view': Header
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.header-bg {
  background: red;
}

.header-bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <header-view :bg="headerBg"></header-view>
  <user-name name="Varit"></user-name>
  <last-name></last-name>
</div>
```